# Modify Dates in a certain format in an array of objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, formatting, javascript-objects

I am trying to modify the dates in an object in below format. Basically I want to first convert the string date into date format, then try to get the year and decide if it's 1st half of the year i.e. from 2023.01.01 to **H1' 2023** or 2nd half of the year i.e. from 2023.07.01 to  **H2'2023** and then update the dates. Really appreciate your help Thanks

```
// Current Data set 

data = [{'description': 'halfyear', date: '2024.01.01'},
    {'description': 'halfyear', date: '2024.07.01'},
    {'description': 'halfyear', date: '2016.01.01'},
    {'description': 'halfyear', date: '2016.07.01'}
    ]
```

```
// Expected Data 

data = [{'description': 'halfyear', date: 'H1\'2024'},
    {'description': 'halfyear', date: 'H2\'2024'},
    {'description': 'halfyear', date: 'H1\'2016'},
    {'description': 'halfyear', date: 'H2\'2016'}
    ]
```

I have tried below but it doesn't seem to update correctly and override the values.

```
data.map(x=> {
 return x.formatted = 'H' + ' ' + new Date(x.date).getMonth() + 1 < 6 ? '1': '2' + new Date(x.date).getFullYear() + ''
})
```

Current Data-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX9EK.png

Expected Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tcMO.png

Comment: The attempt to put all the logic into one line yields different results than you expect. For example, the `<` sign compares the number 6 to the string you built on the left, so it's always false.

Comment: In addition, if you want to override the `date` property then you don't need to use a new `formatted` property. And finally, you don't need to use `map` and to return any value, you just need `data.forEach`. While it doesn't break anything, it's redundant since you aren't using the mapped new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion while managing brackets and operator precedence I would recommend using template literals. Also you don't need to add to the month `1` since the math is already working (`< 6`).

```js
const data = [
    { 'description': 'halfyear', date: '2024.01.01' },
    { 'description': 'halfyear', date: '2024.07.01' },
    { 'description': 'halfyear', date: '2016.01.01' },
    { 'description': 'halfyear', date: '2016.07.01' }
];

// if you need a copy
const mapped = data.map(({date, description}) => {
    const [year, month] = date.split('.');
    return {
      description,
      date: `H${month < 6 ? 1 : 2}\'${year}`
    };
});

// if you need in-place transform
data.forEach(item => {
    const [year, month] = item.date.split('.');
    item.date = `H${month < 6 ? 1 : 2}\'${year}`;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: @Shelly you are welcome) btw fixed a bug - removed a leftover round bracket in the end of the result date string. also upvoted your question to add you reputation so you can upvote my answer too (the arrow up) ;-)

Comment: @RobG fixed, so hope you will retract your downvote

Answer (score 0):

It's inefficient to parse the string to a *Date* just to call a method to get back the month value when it's available directly from the string. It's particularly problematic to use the built–in Date parser with an unsupported string format.

To modify the value of the *date* property based on the month, just parse out the month and see if it's `< 7`. E.g.

```js
let data = [
 {'description': 'halfyear', date: '2024.01.01'},
 {'description': 'halfyear', date: '2024.07.01'},
 {'description': 'halfyear', date: '2016.01.01'},
 {'description': 'halfyear', date: '2016.07.01'}
];

let data2 = data.map(obj => {
  let [y, m, d] = obj.date.split(/\D/);
  return {...obj, date: `H${m < 7? 1: 2}'${y}`}; 
});

console.log(data2)
```

#### PS

An issue in the OP is the following expression (looking at just the part up to and including the conditional expression):

```
'H' + ' ' + new Date(x.date).getMonth() + 1 < 6 ? '1': '2'
```

This is evaluated as:

```
('H' + ' ' + new Date(x.date).getMonth() + 1) < 6 ? '1': '2'
```

If `new Date(x.date).getMonth()` returns say 3, the comparison expression resolves to:

```
('H' + ' ' + 3 + 1) < 6
```

which evaluates to (noting that the addition operator `+` is evaluated left to right and since the first expression is a string, each subsequent expression is converted to string before being added):

```
'H 31' < 6
```

The less than operator `<` uses the [abstract relational algorithm](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison). It first converts the operands to primitive and if the result isn't two strings, converts them to numbers. `toNumber('H 31')` returns `NaN`, so now you have:

```
NaN < 6
```

This expression evaluates to *undefined* (step 4.d), regardless of the value returned by *getMonth* (an integer in the range 0 to 11 or NaN):

```
undefined ? '1' : '2'
```

Now the algorithm for the [conditional operator `? :`](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-conditional-operator) kicks in and calls *toBoolean* on the left hand side, which returns false:

```
false ? '1' : '2'
```

So the result will always be '2'.

To get the result you want, add some brackets to force the conditional expression to be evaluated without interference from the surrounding code:

```
'H' + ' ' + (new Date(x.date).getMonth() + 1 < 6 ? '1': '2') + new Date(x.date).getFullYear() + ''
```

An extra set of brackets might help with readability:

```
'H' + ' ' + ((new Date(x.date).getMonth() + 1) < 6 ? '1': '2') + new Date(x.date).getFullYear() + ''
```

This of course assumes that `new Date(x.date)` returns a valid *Date*, which, in the OP, it doesn't in some implementations. :-(